# Python: start many scripts at the same time

Tags: python, shell, scripting

This program starts the first program. But I also want to run the second parallel.
How can i start two or more programs with a script?

```
# start many programs
execfile('C:/Dokumente und Einstellungen/schnei17/Desktop/python/zeit/1.py')
print 1
execfile('C:/Dokumente und Einstellungen/schnei17/Desktop/python/zeit/2.py')
print 2
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `subprocess` for this?

Comment: `subprocess` makes this much easier unless you need to share data between the processes in which case you would use `multiprocessing`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with the subprocess python module :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["python.exe", 'C:/Dokumente und Einstellungen/schnei17/Desktop/python/zeit/1.py'])
subprocess.Popen(["python.exe", 'C:/Dokumente und Einstellungen/schnei17/Desktop/python/zeit/2.py'])
```

It will launch the 2 scripts in parallel (if your python.exe is in PATH).

Comment: I get an error: WindowsError: [Error 193]  (it is not a win-32 application)

Comment: I updated with the python.exe call before script name, you can replace python.exe by the full path to your python executable

Answer (score 0):

To start several applications I'd recommend to use threading.

```
shellcommands=("notepad.exe",
               "calc.exe",
               "mspaint.exe")

import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
import threading
import subprocess

class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    # Override Thread's __init__ method to accept the parameters needed:

    def __init__ ( self, command ):
        self.command = command
        threading.Thread.__init__ ( self )

    def run(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print "%s %s %s \n" % (self.getName(), self.command,now)
        try:
            subprocess.call(self.command, shell=True)
        except Exception, err:
            print "ERROR: %s\n" % str(err)

for cmd in shellcommands:
    t = ThreadClass(cmd)
    t.start()

sys.exit()
```

Comment: That will leave python running too, and block on the console.  Unless this is intended, it's better to use subprocess.